# Showing a marker at a geo:-url in Android Maps

Tags: android, android-intent, url-scheme

Is it possible not only to have Google Maps on Android show a given coordinate in the Maps Application but have also a marker (or pin) set at the location?

I read the documentation at https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html but it only lets me set the zoom level.

Right now I use the following code to show a place in Google Maps on Android:

```
Double lat = 53.3;
Double lng = 13.4;
final String uriString = "geo:" + lat + ',' + lng + "?z=15";
Intent showOnMapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString));
startActivity(showOnMapIntent);
```

Is it possible to have a marker there or do I need to use a MapActivity?
Where can I find the complete documentation on the url parameters that the Maps application understands?

Can I use a different url prefix? For example "https://maps.google.de/maps?"? 
Maps has an intent-filter matching this scheme/host/pathPrefix. 
Where can I find documentation on which parameters Google Maps for Android actually supports with this url?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works with the follwoing url:

```
final String uriString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + lat + ',' + lng + "("+ label +")&z=15";
```

The reverse geo coded address is shown.

I found documentation to the supported parameters [here](http://querystring.org/google-maps-query-string-parameters/). This is not the documentation for Androids Google Maps but what I tried works.

Note: it should be noted that the original question was in regards to the the geo: URI to launch the Google Maps app (see [Android Developer Reference Intents List](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), whereas this answer might launch a web view with the Google Maps website depending on what App the user chooses for this Intent.

Comment: thats coolm but unfortunately then google-earth does not catch the link - a mix of both would be cool ;-)

Comment: The above link is not working anymore. Should maybe be replaced with this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro?hl=en

Answer (score 12):

Dirk, have you tried `geo:0,0?q=lat,lng`?

it is displaying a marker on my nexus 5.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://maps.google.com/?saddr=34.052222,-118.243611

and to get the complete route between two points:

http://maps.google.com/?saddr=34.052222,-118.243611&daddr=37.322778,-122.031944