# Run Native Android Google Maps from webpage

Tags: android, html, mobile, google-maps-api-3, mobile-browser

Is it possible, to run native google maps app, that shows elements from my WebApp map?

For example: I have map with marker on my office Address and i want to run Application google maps ( of course with user permission ) on client Android Phone with my office selected?

Like

```
mailto:email@example.com
```

is for emails, but for places on map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've found it

[Geo_URI - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI)

Sorry for that.

Edit:
Even better
[same topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744863/showing-a-marker-at-a-geo-url-in-android-maps)